# Using List boxes to delete columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, listbox, datagridviewcolumn

I have two list boxes, a datagridview and an Add and Remove button. Listbox1 contains the headers for the columns of the datagridview. Listbox2 contains the list of columns(with headers) currently displayed on the datagridview.

What I can't figure out to do is: when you select a header from the first listbox and hit the Add button how can I get a column with that header to appear on the datagridview?

Do I need to bind the string values of the column headers to a column and then have them add and delete when the correct button is pressed? confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to show and hide column

Hide

`dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false`

Show

`dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = true`

Answer (score 0):

I would have all of the columns already added, but have the visibility set so that they aren't shown if they shouldn't be.  When you click the button to "add a column" just find that column by name and change the visibility.  Same for removing it.

Then you don't need to worry about re-binding or anything like that.